# What am I doing wrong with the else if statements

Tags: c++, if-statement

The program tells me that it expects a statement with the else if statements. I'm really new and I'm trying to learn c ++ code before I take any CS class when I do go to college. Thanks in advance!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
string color;
string Blue;
string Green;
string Brown;

int age;
int main()
{
    cout << "what is the color of your eyes ? (use capitalization)" << endl << "colors to choose from are " << endl << "Blue" << endl << "Green" << endl << "Brown";
    cin >> color;

    if (color == Blue); {
        cout << "you are an intelligent person " << endl;
        system("pause");
    }
    else if (color == Green); {
        cout << " you are a peaceful person " << endl;
        system("pause");
    }
    else if (color == Brown); {
        cout << "you are a normal go get 'em person " << endl;
        system("pause");
    }


    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: "...wrong with the else if statements..." - I was so sure you'd have put the `else` statements before the `if`, but seems you navigated that hurdle admirably.  Johan's got your back.

Comment: What happens if my eyes are neither of those colours?

Comment: @NeilKirk: Then you will never pause... :-(

Comment: If any of the answers solved your issue, please mark the best correct answer as "solved" for future people visiting this question =)

Comment: @ Johan by ranking do you mean making the check mark green?? Hahaha

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your problem is that you have semi-colons after the parenthesis. This:

```
if (color == Blue); {
    cout << "you are an intelligent person " << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Should be this

```
                 No semi colon here
                  v
if (color == Blue) {
    cout << "you are an intelligent person " << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

And the same for the rest of your else-ifs

also, as others have mentioned, you need to specify what Blue, Green and Brown are. Either do it this way:

```
const string Blue = "Blue";
const string Green = "Green";
const string Brown = "Brown";
```

Or if you want:

```
 if (color == "Blue") {   //Note the ""
    cout << "you are an intelligent person " << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Thank you I have found that out as I was working on it and through other replies I found out that doing what you told me are called string literals...did not know they had such a name or that I did anything... but I just put quotation marks and doing that actually made my "program" work. Hahahaha Thank you for your reply and sorry for such a noob post I should of checked for stupid things like those semicolons in the if statements.

Comment: @dstaticnum No worries, we have all been beginners =) Glad that it worked out for you

Answer (score 3):

You have placed semicolons where they don't belong. You also need to give values to the string you use to compare:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string color;
string Blue = "Blue";
string Green = "Green";
string Brown = "Brown";

    int age;

    cout << "what is the color of your eyes ? (use capitalization)" << endl << "colors to choose from are " << endl << "Blue" << endl << "Green" << endl << "Brown";
    cin >> color;

    if (color == Blue)
    {
        cout << "you are an intelligent person " << endl;
        system("pause");
    }
    else if (color == Green)
    {
        cout << " you are a peaceful person " << endl;
        system("pause");
    }
    else if (color == Brown)
    {
        cout << "you are a normal go get 'em person " << endl;
        system("pause");
    }

    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply I also noticed that...I should of looked for things like that before posting...hahaha Im just a real noob. I also figured out that with C++ I could actually use one string variable like string color, and then when making the if statements I could compare what the "user" typed in like so if(color== "Blue") and even check if what you type in to the "program" is those three colors like so if( color != "Blue" etc.). So thank you I am really glad you replied.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove erroneous semicolons after the if  and else if statements, as follows:

```
if (color == Blue) {
    cout << "you are an intelligent person " << endl;
    system("pause");
}
else if (color == Green) {
    cout << " you are a peaceful person " << endl;
    system("pause");
}
else if (color == Brown) {
    cout << "you are a normal go get 'em person " << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Thank you I have actually noticed that mistake an found out that I can use various if statements and come up with one else statement. So I sorta figured it out by myself...such a noob. Thank you for the reply though.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ you can regard `;` as a *statement terminator*.

Something like `if (color == "Blue");` is a statement in its own right. But it doesn't do anything since `;` terminates the `if` statement.

Furthermore, it's possible to group statements using the braces `{` and `}`. Indeed this can be useful to limit the scope of any variables declared within the braces. You'll discover the positive effects this has on program stability in due course.

To cut a long story short, once you've fixed your dodgy string comparisons (you need to use quotation characters for literals as I have done above), your code is perfectly valid syntatically. That's why it compiles. (Although a good compiler ought to warn you about the empty `if` control block). But it's not doing what you want: you need to remove the extraneous `;` on all your lines containing `if`.

Comment: That's exactly what I did I figured out that in C++ you can actually compare text or strings within if statements like you said, so those things are called literals.. thank you. I hope to learn more about what your talking about with the braces {} hahaha. Sorry for such a noob post. And thanks a lot for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

As well as the extra semicolons, you haven't actually initialized the string values, so they are all empty strings.  You need to add at the start:

```
Blue = "Blue";
Green = "Green";
Brown = "Brown";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variables `Blue`, `Green` and `Brown` are empty string variables.

```
string Blue; // empty string with name Blue
string Green; // empty string with name Green
string Brown; // empty string with name Brown
```

First of all you need to remove the worng semicolons and you need to use strings with content.
You can just leave out your variables and use string literals instead:

```
if (color == "Blue") {
```

Or you need to fill in some data into your strings:

```
std::string Blue("Blue");
// ...
if (color == Blue); {
```

Comment: Yes they were empty string variables ..and I figured that out that you can use string literals. Sorry for such a noob post again I am doing this to learn and get a feel of coding before I go into college so learning from and having people to reply to such a noob post was cool hahahahaha...I really like this website.